# Content Not Loading Into Div Upon Click (w. jQuery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I've been staring at this issue all morning now, and I just cannot see where my problem is. I've looked at most other "load content into div upon click" posts, and all the jQuery scripts/div ID's seem to be same with what I have.

Essentially, I have a card on my page with 2 links as header, "Content A" and "Content B." I'd like the `card-body` to change dynamically as someone clicks between Content A and Content B.

I'm making the site with Django, if that makes any difference.

The card is from Bootstrap.

This is my code:

```
<div class="card text-center" style="width: 800px;">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#actionA" style="color:#1DA1F2" id="actionA">Show Content A</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#actionB" style="color:#1DA1F2" id="actionB">Show Content B</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" id="tweetcontent">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $("#actionA").on("click", function(){
        $("#tweetcontent").load("top10pos.html");
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

All `top10pos.html` has inside is just `<p>Content A</p>` (testing), and it's in the same directory as the HTML file with the above card code.

What am I doing wrong? Everything seems to be following what most other posts said was a fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network and make sure it is succeeding (status 200) and returning what you expect

Comment: Looks like I'm getting a Django error. On my machine, my currently URL is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sentiments/?username=realDonaldTrump#actionA, and the request URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/sentiments/top10pos.html. I'm guessing  its a URL error than jQuery error, thank you for pointing out the browser dev tools!

Comment: I thought .load() was opening an html file in a specific directory. Why does it involve a request.URL?

Comment: What is happening exactly when you click "Show content A". Does anything happen at all? Your javascript code is inside of your tweetcontent div that you are replacing. This may have something to do with the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Robert-Sony, nothing on the page itself changes, except the URL gets a "#contentA" tag at the end. Other than that, the page just looks the same.

Comment: have you tried wrapping code inside $(document).ready(function(){ }); wrapper ... may be that is the issue the dom is not loaded still and the event is not being attached.

Comment: `... id="tweetcontent">` you are replacing the html inside it with `$("#tweetcontent").load("top10pos.html");` If i am not wrong, then you get the 1st result but clicking on any of them brokes it

Comment: ok I see. I would first recommend moving your code outside of the tweetcontent div. Possibly put it at the very end of your file and see if anything changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe the DOM is not fully loaded upon execution of this `.load()`.

Try wrapping your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ });
```

Let me know your results - I'll keep thinking of other possibilities.

Comment: Also - have you done debugging to see if anything is breaking the code?

Comment: Your wrapper did fix it! Another issue was the URL, as Django was not recognizing "top10pos.html" as anything, so nothing was actually being loaded into the div. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help.  happy coding!

Comment: Do you know how I can just load snippets of HTML with the jQuery function? I'd essentially just want to be loading in ``<div class="card-content">``.

Comment: You can use '$("#destinationElement").load("path/to/file.html");' to load html snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Error As i Guess! The js will replace itself on the first click.

```
<div class="card-body" id="tweetcontent">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $("#actionA").on("click", function(){
        $("#tweetcontent").load("top10pos.html");
      });
    </script>
</div>
```

**Here is what solution will look like**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card text-center" style="width: 800px;">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#actionA" style="color:#1DA1F2" id="actionA">Show Content A</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#actionB" style="color:#1DA1F2" id="actionB">Show Content B</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" id="tweetcontent">
    <p>Anything Here will be replaced</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
   $("#actionA").on("click", function(){
    $("#tweetcontent").load("https://enable-cors.org/");
  });

  $("#actionB").on("click", function(){
    $("#tweetcontent").load("https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/");
  });
</script>
```

Run it here! For Fiddle go [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/xpvt214o/589055/)

```js
 $("#actionA").on("click", function(){
  $("#tweetcontent").load("https://enable-cors.org/");
});

$("#actionB").on("click", function(){
  $("#tweetcontent").load("https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.card-body{
  background: #ddd;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card text-center" style="width: 800px;">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#actionA" style="color:#1DA1F2" id="actionA">Show Content A</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#actionB" style="color:#1DA1F2" id="actionB">Show Content B</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" id="tweetcontent">
    <p>Anything Here will be replaced</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Instead of a webpage, how do you load just snippets of HTML code?

Comment: `load()` does the work here, but If you want to get only some part of the page, then do `request.get` in backend of django view and you can parse there using **beautifulsoup** and send html text you need to your template.